# Laravel on Cpanel shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cpanel

I have gone through most of the articles online and none of the solution worked.

I have my project installed in `/home/projectname` directory and created a symlink `/home/projectname/public` to `/username/public_html`

Storage directory is linked as well.

So far I have tried following

1) Set file permission using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel) answer

2) I have checked that necessary extensions are installed using `php -m` command.

3) Also tried to move files from `/home/projctname/public` directory to `/home/public_html` and change the necessary files like `server.php`,`index.php` and `AppServiceProvider.php`

None of the above worked.

Strange thing is if I have `index.html` in `public` folder that file and content is accessed fine but `index.php` file is not executed.

I tried echo out some string from `/home/projectname/public/index.php` but it seems like that `index.php` is not being executed.

What else can I try to fix my problem?

Thank you

Comment: It hards to identify your error, better please copy or screenshot the error message put here. Anyway please make sure it has public/.htaccess?

Comment: @KakadaNeang it has .htaccess in project public directory and I have made no changes there

Comment: So make sure the content of .htaccess file the same as your local file, because sometime cpanel has been modified it. Other things check your web server, does it able to read the public/index.php file?

Comment: @KakadaNeang that's the problem it can read `index.html` in the public folder but not `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help, but two quick things to check. Not sure what OS you are running, but if something like Ubuntu with Apache2, you could check

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Making sure index.php is first. and then do you have a virtual hosts file?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/your-project/public

    <Directory /home/your-project>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```